# compute shortest distance to a different sink

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, dijkstras-algorithm

Given a directed graph G=(V, E) and a sink vertex t. Edge costs may be negative, zero,
or positive. consider d(v) contains the length of the shortest path from v to t
Given a new sink t2 in the graph, how can we compute the shortest distance for each vertex
to this sink t2 using the originally given function d

**My Thoughts:**
I think the Dijkstra algorithm could be used here, but not sure. As the graph may have negative
cost edges too. And if I use Dijkstra directly, I am not taking advantage of the
extra information given.

Comment: If you are interested in all shortest paths to **all** possible "sink" nodes, then you might want to use [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)

Comment: @nirshahar Here, it's only about one sink. So we already have the shortest path to a given sink, and now we change the sink, and we need to somehow update the distance values for each node. So the problem is about a single sink only.